# Reg ex in a model definition?

Tags: django

I'm currently trying to create a model with an email element, and I'd like to validate the model only if the email is like x@z or x.y@z. Is it possible to add reg ex in models ? I'm kinda new to Django !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use [`EmailField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#emailfield) and leave the validation to django framework.

However, if you still want to have your own validations, use [`validator`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/validators/) property for the model field.

```
from django.db import models

def validate_email(value):
    #do your email value validation
    #if invalid, raise ValidationError("Message")

class MyModel(models.Model):
    email_field = models.EmailField(validators=[validate_email])
```

Comment: Oh I didn't know it exist. Thanks !

Comment: Thanks for editing, I was gonna ask it anyway because I'll need it later. I'm done here thanks to you ! :)